# Nothing is printing on terminal when I'm trying to give cmd an nmap command through python

Tags: python, networking, ip-address, nmap

I'm trying to build a web scanner for a networks project using python. I wanted to use nmap for this to list the devices connected to a host with some IP address. For example, here I'm using the IP address of wikipedia.com.

```
import os

def get_nmap(options, ip):
     command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
     process = os.popen(command)
     results = str(process.read())
     return results


print(get_nmap('-F', '103.102.166.226'))
```

This is the code I wrote. The command 'nmap -Pn -F 103.102.166.226' itself is running fine on my terminal. But when I run the program, nothing is printed. Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The code works just fine, the output will be printed after the scanning process is finished. My guess is that you have a connection problem, try changing the IP to your local address 127.0.0.1 and see if there's any differences.

```
import os

def get_nmap(options, ip):
     command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
     process = os.popen(command)
     results = str(process.read())
     return results


print(get_nmap('-F', '127.0.0.1'))
```

Comment: Hey, the code still isn't working on my system. I think my network is fine because the command seems to be working in cmd perfectly. I don't know.